# Как выполнить js функцию HTML из SVG в объекте?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

```
 <object
  type="image/svg+xml"
  data="display.svg">

 <script type="text/javascript">
   function hop(name, evt) {
        console.log('!!!')
   }
 </script>
```

Или как инжектнуть скрипт в объект?

Цель получить клик по `<path>` с параметрами `evt.target` или хотяб `id` в js главного фрейма.

Comment: что вы имели в виду? что значит из svg обьекта? какой-то текст или элемент должен попасть в svg элемент?

Comment: ಠ_ಠ А что вообще ожидается в результате парсинга этой штуки, объявление функции? Задача в целом тоже непонятна, т.е. неясно как вообще должен работать вызов "из SVG объекта" при том что SVG это всего лишь декларативная разметка (которая ничего вызывать/выполнять не может даже по определению).

Comment: @yar85 не просто разметка, но и pointer-events и css. ознакомьтесь с темой сначала

Comment: Я бы с радостью ознакомился с тем как разметка выполняет работу браузера, но не знаю где тот волшебный шкаф через который можно попасть в твою реальность...

Comment: @highpassion событие клик ловить

Comment: @yar85 так вот он https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/interact.html

Comment: если встроить  напрямую в боди, то будет работать. но хочу отделить мух от котлет)

Comment: Для такого отделения, нужно как минимум представлять как выглядит котлета, и как выглядит муха - но по вoпросу похоже что он не делает различий между элементом `<object>` и SVG-**документом** (оставим пока забавную теорию том что скрипты выполняет вовсе не браузер, а разметка). То есть, скрипт в твоем примере выполняется не в SVG-документе, а в основном (предполагается HTML). Мне вот кажется естественным, что для выполнения скриптов в другом документе, надо просто поместить их в этот "другой" документ - а тебе так не кажется?

Comment: svg это не object - я вкурсе (svg внутри #document, который внутри object). да и теория что разметка выполняет скипты Ваша)))

Comment: поместить их в другой документ сложно потому как взаимодействие внутри svg должно взаимодействовать с интерфейсом html и svg будет верстать человек без навыков js

Comment: _«будет верстать человек без навыков js»_ - а, ну тогда понятно. Конечно, я бы предложил бандлер использовать для внедрения кода в результат работы человека, но думаю что и на это найдется аргумент против, так что...))

Comment: бандлер) это как вы умно назвали tail+cat )
встраивание js кода не проблема - проблема во взаимодействии. идеально было бы пропихнуть код c топ фрейма в object, чтоб запустить там взаимодействие через window.parent.postMessage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пока сделал на `jquery`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id=map></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function hop(name, evt) {
        console.log('!!!')
    } 
    window.onload = (function (){
      $('#map').load('display.svg')
    })
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

svg вставляется в div без обертки object, скрипт внутри и снаружи исполняется как нужно.

Функция `hop` вызфвается из

```
   ...
    <path
       style="fill:#00cc00;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.264583px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1"
       d="m 74.646387,123.56036 -0.02103,-12.25607 -12.697325,-0.0459 -0.07117,12.29129 z"
       id="path1079"
       onmouseover="hop('вошел',evt)"
       onmouseout="hop('вышел',evt)" />
```

Comment: То есть, здесь есть ответ на вопрос "Как выполнить js функцию HTML из SVG объекта"? Объекта нет, функция только объявлена и нигде не вызывается, используется fetch чтобы подгрузить и вставить (?) SVG... Как в итоге выглядит DOM после вставки? Как из этого чего-то вызвать функцию? Функцию HTML?

Comment: это воркэраунд - нет объекта - нет проблем)

Comment: Так можно просто вставить SVG как инлайн HTML "объект", даже соблюдать соглашения XML не надо - это буквально элементы DOM, с которыми можно работать как с любыми другими в плане прописывания событий "onmouseover" и так далее. И у меня ощущение, что вы ничего не получите в evt. Можно вообще не лезть в HTML с вызовами функций, а прописать слушателей в коде JS.

Comment: Интересная задачка...утром попробую ...

Comment: @MaximLensky, имеется ввиду - попробую понять?))) Пока ничего не понятно.

Comment: Нет, попробую сделать что то из object

Comment: @Leonid получаю нормальный свгшный эвент.