# Как подключить svg отдельным файлом в HTML

Tags: css3, html5, svg, viewbox

```html
<svg width="995" height="1006" viewBox="0 0 995 1006" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="M247.666 717.014L499.294 0.404095L994.083 576.626L247.666 717.014Z" fill="#2F80ED"/>
                    </svg>
<svg width="995" height="1006" viewBox="0 0 995 1006" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="M247.666 717.014L499.294 0.404095L994.083 576.626L247.666 717.014Z" fill="#2F80ED"/>
                    </svg>
```

Comment: <svg width="995" height="1006" viewBox="0 0 995 1006" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="M247.666 717.014L499.294 0.404095L994.083 576.626L247.666 717.014Z" fill="#2F80ED"/>
                    </svg>

Comment: вот посмотрите [топик](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1377169/28748), возможно будет полезно при решении вашего вопроса

Answer (score 1):

Можно подключить через тег img `<img src="img/icon.svg" alt="icon">`.

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно отдельным файлом, то вставляйте его так же, как обычное изображение, то есть:

```
<img src="file.svg" alt="...">
```

Единственно, что тогда у вас не будет доступа к нему из CSS и JS, но это и не всегда нежно.

Answer (score 1):

Или как объект - ведет себя как iframe, ближе всего к прямой вставке:

```
<object data="/static/image.svg" width="300" height="300"> </object>
```

Или как картинка - ведет как картинка:

```
<img src="/static/image.svg">
```

Ещё можно как iframe.

Но чтоб можно было скриптовать или как-то взаимодействовать с картинкой - то только через JS - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1314519/16574